# ArcGIS Online free account limitations?

Tags: arcgis-online, limitations

I've been trying to do a few things with an ArcGIS Online free account, but they're not working the same way as with my various subscription and Organisation accounts.

Is there a feature limitation list or feature comparison available online that outlines what can and can't be done with a free ArcGIS Online account?

I did find an old link that sounds like there once was a comparison available, however this link now just redirects to ArcGIS Online product page (which ironically has the tagline *Mapping Without Limits*), and I can't find any comparison charts or limitation lists there.

The old link was [ArcGIS Online - Features - Comparison Table](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgisonline/features/comparison-table)

Please note that this is the Personal/Free ArcGIS Online, and not the free Organisation trial.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the limitations for ArcGIS Online Public accounts I am aware of are (from memory):

- storage limited to 2 GB
- cannot login in to ArcGIS Collector and other premium apps
- can't participate in groups
- sharing is limited to yourself or the entire Internet
- can't access premium content (stuff that consumes credits in an organization account)

Despite all this I still find the AGOL Public accounts very useful.

Comment: I am aware of these differences, however I am after an authoritative list of functionality limitations, such as the inability to create feature layers

Comment: Is the free subscription limited for a certain period?

Answer (score 0):

Providing "an authoritative list of functionality limitations" is something that only the vendor, in this case Esri, can do.

If you seek a list from outside Esri then I think, since none has been identified after nearly a month, this should be approached by investigating a perceived limitation a question at a time here, or by posting an ArcGIS Idea to have Esri provide (an updated) one.